# Fiddler: How to use oSession.utilFindInResponse in gzip encoded response

Tags: gzip, fiddler, rules, break

I'm trying to use Fiddler to break when the response contains a specific word and edit the response live.
However, it seems that the *oSession.utilFindInResponse* function does not match successfully because the response is using GZIP encoding.
Is it possible to get around this ?
I'm new to fiddlers rules but there might be a way to change http compression on the fly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling oSession.utilDecodeResponse() on the session object will remove HTTP chunking and compression from the response.